# php mysql query email alert sends multiple duplicate emails

Tags: php, mysql, email

My issue is when the form is submitted it sends an email alerting other users that have previously filled a survey for that exact camp that a new survey entry has been entered for that camp location, the problem is if the person has entered 3 surveys for that camp location the user gets 3 emails, Since my database has sometimes has entries from the same user email for each camp location.

This is what is the problem

$to_add = $row['Email'];

How do I make sure it does not send an email to the user multiple times?

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM Camp_Survey_Submits WHERE CampName = '$campname3'";
$result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


$from_add = "support@hikelospadres.com"; 
$to_add = $row['Email']; 
$subject = "New Report Has Been Submitted to ".$row['CampName']." ";
$message = "Hello ".$row['SurveyorName'].", <br>
We noticed that you have previously filled out a survey for ".$row['CampName'].", so we just wanted to inform you that a new report has been added to ".$row['CampName'].". <br>  To see this latest report, please go to: <a href='".$row['Referrer']."'><b> ".$row['Referrer']." </b></a>. <br>
Thank you,<br><br><br>
<b>Hike Los Padres<b><br>
www.hikelospadres.com<br>
```

`

Comment: Select distinct emails but I am guessing that your table is not normalized (don't store the user's email, store his/her id instead)

Comment: Like KA_lin said. The problem is quite obvious, and you have stated that in your database has duplicate entries. If you don't want to do a distinct like suggested, you can order by email, and keep track of the last email that was used.

Comment: Thanks, but they are not duplicate entries, just multiple surveys for the same camp by the same person, my problem is that the when a new survey is filled for a camp out I want to email anyone that has previously filled out a survey for that camp to let them know that a new one has been entered, how do I just make it so it will only email the person once, not multiple times. 

`$to_add = $row['Email'];`

Comment: Thank you all so much, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is input each email into an array when the `while` is running and then check, before the email sends, if that email already exists in the array or not.

Do this:

```
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM Camp_Survey_Submits WHERE CampName = '$campname3'";
    $result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

    $emails = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    if ( !in_array($row['Email'],$emails)) {

    $from_add = "support@hikelospadres.com"; 
    $to_add = $row['Email']; 
    $subject = "New Report Has Been Submitted to ".$row['CampName']." ";
    $message = "Hello ".$row['SurveyorName'].", <br>
    We noticed that you have previously filled out a survey for ".$row['CampName'].", so we just wanted to inform you that a new report has been added to ".$row['CampName'].". <br>  To see this latest report, please go to: <a href='".$row['Referrer']."'><b> ".$row['Referrer']." </b></a>. <br>
    Thank you,<br><br><br>
    <b>Hike Los Padres<b><br>
    www.hikelospadres.com<br>";

    mail(); // send the mail using the mail function (or PHP Mailer, etc.)

    array_push($emails,$row['Email']);
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$emails = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $emails[$row['Email']] = array(
        'from_add' => "support@hikelospadres.com", 
        'to_add' => $row['Email'], 
        'subject' => "New Report Has Been Submitted to ".$row['CampName'],
        'message' => "Hello ".$row['SurveyorName']
    );
}


foreach($emails as $email){
  mail($email['to_add'], $email['subject'], $email['message']);
}
```

first you build your array, overwrite the key by email, then loop again to send.

Perhaps there are better way, just an idea